# need to use www.mydomain.com/filename/ instead of www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

[www.mydomain.com/filename/](http://www.mydomain.com/filename/)  instead of  [www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1](http://www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1)

currently im developing a Auto index site script

From index.php i had put a hyper link to download page Download page  and on file.php page i had put

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "update mydatabase SET views = views+1 where id ='".$id."'";
$update = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * from mydatabase where id='".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


<?php echo $row['id'];?>
<?php echo $row['name'];?>
<?php echo $row['size'];?>
```

etc..

when i click on Download page it redirect me to [www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1](http://www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1)  page and show the related file details.

But i really need to change the above url as [www.mydomain.com/song/file-name](http://www.mydomain.com/song/file-name)

please can anybody advise or help me on this ??

Comment: hi Ayesha, welcome to stackoverflow. i dont think you can turn `/file.php?id=1` to `/song/filename/` with htaccess alone. you have to use the filename itself as parameter for the query string so htaccess can work it out. once you used filename as parameter, you could solve your rewrite with `RewriteRule "^song/(.+)" "file.php?filename=$1"` (some nuances need to be addressed though).

Comment: i had changed my code as "song.php?title=$title" it also working fine can i now change the url from .htaccess ??

Comment: yes, the rule then become `RewriteRule "^song/(.+)" "song.php?title=$1"` however, my memory is kinda fuzzy, there are things that need to be considered such as actual files/folder. but give it a shot first.

Comment: how can i avoid sql injections for above code pls help me??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this on your download page.

```
history.replaceState(null, null, '/song/file-name')
```

Comment: from where can i put tis code?? Download page header??

Comment: The above is the js code, put it in the script tag.